# CSS vertical align image inside another div (Divi wordpress theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center my image verticaly inside div. I have a set of images that are different heights and widths. I made a boxes 320x230 that displays that images inside them. Images that are bigger have overflow: hidden. But some images that are smaller have gap so I want to center them on this website --- > [Here](http://79.170.40.178/frankogojkovic.com/transformations/)

I use this CSS for the DIV that contains image

```
.transformations {

max-width:320px;
max-height: 230px;
min-width:320px;
min-height: 230px;
box-shadow: 0 0 50px #0052af;
overflow: hidden;
border: 4px solid #0052af;
}
```

Comment: How you host your website as that O.o!

Comment: That is just a temporary link used for developing a website. I didn't connected it yet to a live domain, so I use this link. I think every host has that option. I use https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

I have just made some customizations and it works:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

And css:

```
.img-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:425px;
}

.img-wrapper img{
   position: absolute;
   top:-100%; left:0; right: 0; bottom:-100%;
   margin: auto;
}
```

That worked for me on Divi wordpress theme.